# Create a virtual serial port for widcomm stack under 32feet

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-mobile-6, virtual-serial-port

Currently I am doing a project involves a bluetooth communication setup between a PDA and a small embedded device. This small embedded device can only be communicated with a virtual serial port over a bluetooth link.

The PDA is the ipaq running with windows mobile 6, and I am using c#.

I had done a program which can communication with the serial port over bluetooth. But the only issue is every time I run this program, I have to active the bluetooth radio, and manually pairing this device with the pda via the bluetooth manager. What I want to do is when running this program, it can establish the bluetooth connection between the pda and the embedded module.

So I am using functions from the 32feet prject. This is one issue is I cant make the virutal serial port part, as I think the 32feet project can only make virual serial ports for the window bluetooth stack but not the widcomm bluetooth stact, which the ipaq is using.

Therefore, are there any existing c# classes or stacks that can make virtual serial port under widcomm for windows mobile 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See my answer at [Widcomm bluetooth : how to open the virtual COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004730/widcomm-bluetooth-how-to-open-the-virtual-com).  I generally recommend using a direct sockets (BluetoothClient) connection. That seems better to me than having to create a virtual serial port, which is difficult on various platforms, and then open it, and then gets no errors when the peer device goes out of range etc etc. :-)

Alan